# Integrating SPA-like behavior in existing .NET 2.0 Web Form Application

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, angularjs

I maintain a large .Net 2.0 web forms application. My users were complaining about the clunkiness and slow speed of one part of the app. So I created a JSON web service that interfaces with the existing app's business layer and rebuilt the front-end in Single Page Application style as a proof of concept. Users love it. I basically rolled my own JS/JQuery.

My question: What JavaScript framework would be the most suitable in my situation (Angular?). My JS/JQuery code works, but would be a mess for someone else to maintain. Any suggestions/guidance would be welcome. Rebuilding the app is not an option, and really not necessary. I just want to give it a face lift (piece by piece) and would like to use a framework to keep it neat.

Comment: If anyone is interested, I did choose angularjs and it is working out well. You can breath new life into those old .NET webform apps. Users are thrilled and want more of the app converted.